# How to initialize a multidimetional array of unknown size in PHP?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I'm clear on how to go through it once its created, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to initialize it so I can push information in it.

Comment: $arr = array(); and then `$arr[$i][] = some value.... or another so many way to make that $arr variable as multidimensional array`

Comment: I can do that? Without initializing the inner arrays? I hope its this simple. But trying to put a value in $arr[$i][$k] or whatever else it seems you're trying to put a value in an array you have not yet initialized.

Answer (score 1):

There is no special way to declare a multidimensional array. You can just declare it like a normal array, and then push an array into it.

Example:

```
$aar = array(array());
$arr[0][0] = "whatever";
echo $arr[0][0];

//or if you want your own keys

$arr2 = array("First" => array("first_in_first" => ""));
$arr2["first"]["first_in_first"] = "whatever2";
echo $arr2["first"]["first_in_first"];

//with array_push
$arr3 = array();
$array_in_arr3 = array("whatever3");

array_push($arr3, $array_in_arr3);

echo $arr3[0][0];

//Output would be

whateverwhatever2whatever3
```

Comment: See this is the crux of the question I've got in order to do your example you intiated an array inside an array. And I'll sometimes need one and at other times other sizes of those multi dimentional arrays, lets say some times I'll need a 3 x 3 x 3 and other times 5 x 5 x 5. The first comment on top suggested that I could just push stuff without initializing the inner arrays and I'm trying to see if that works now.

Answer (score 0):

is that?

```
$arr = array();

$arr[] = 1;
$arr[] = 2;

$arr['first'] = 1;
$arr['second'] = 2;

$arr['sub']['sub_first'] = 11;

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see how this is helpful, its quite likely I'm just missing the point but I don't understand it.

Comment: you not must initialize array in php.